# How to use emojis in ROBLOX

Tags: windows-10, roblox

An update for Windows 10 came where you can use emoji via the Windows button + period. It is not working on ROBLOX when I am in-game. It works when I am on the ROBLOX website. Someone tell me how to use the emojis in ROBLOX and why they are not working. I can select an emoji, but when I select it, it does not go onto the chat. Other people can use them, however I can't figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Roblox has [stated on their blog](https://blog.roblox.com/2017/07/game-emoji-support/) that on PC you will need to copy and paste emojis into the chat.
What I recommend doing is placing the emoji somewhere (or googling for it) then copy and pasting into the game.

Answer (score 2):

Just google https://getemoji.com highlight the emoji, then press Ctrl C (which is copying) on your keyboard and then go on to ROBLOX, click on the where you chat on ROBLOX, then press Ctrl V (which is pasting) on your keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Use <kbd>Win</kbd> (Windows Key) + <kbd>**.**</kbd> (Dot) to bring up the keyboard shortcut GUI.